# Assigning the length of the result of the query from the await operation to the variable encounters the following problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I use the mongoose operation in Nodejs to query the number of eligible data and assign it to an object property:

```
...
const ability_count = {
    api_count: 0,
    func_count: 0,
    event_count: 0
};
...
ability_count.api_count = await APIService.findByList({cid: comp_id}).length;
ability_count.func_count = await FuncService.findByList({cid: comp_id}).length;
ability_count.event_count = await EventService.findByList({cid: comp_id}).length;
...
const result = {ability_count: ability_count}; rm.successMsg();
rm.setResult(result);
res.send(rm)
```

The result is then returned to the Web, but the ablity_count object that Web receives is missing any property field like this
console.log:

```
result: {
    ability_count: {}
}
```

What causes this?

I know that the await expression is followed by a promise instance, so I can't use.lenth directly, but I still don't know why ability_count doesn't have any properties. Even so I think it should print:

```
result: {
    ability_count: {
        api_count: undefined,
        func_count: undefined,
        event_count: undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `findByList`?

Comment: There is this `ability_count: ablity_count` typo though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would look at the object before it is returned to the client, you'd see that indeed it looks like you expected:

```
{
    ability_count: {
        api_count: undefined,
        func_count: undefined,
        event_count: undefined
    }
}
```

But as the object is to be sent back as an HTTP response, it is serialized to JSON, and at that moment the undefined properties are lost (there is no `undefined` in JSON). Here is a little illustration of that effect:

```js
let result = {
    ability_count: {
        api_count: undefined,
        func_count: undefined,
        event_count: undefined
    }
};

console.log("Original:");
console.log(result);
// Now the object is serialized for the HTTP response:
json = JSON.stringify(result);
console.log("serialized:");
console.log(json);
```

As to the original problem of the `findByList` promises: the `length` property access is made on the promise, and then the `await` operator acts on that `length` property, not on the promise. It should be the other way round: first you want to await the promise, and only when it is resolved, you want to access the `length` property of the value given by `await`. So use parentheses to force the `await` to be executed first:

```
ability_count.api_count = (await APIService.findByList({cid: comp_id})).length;
```